# Select statement in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm trying to display student **individual** attendance records between two dates. When teachers select two dates, the records will be displayed in GridView control. However, I have a problem which other students' attendance records are being displayed too. I can't show only a student attendance records.

This is my C# code, once teacher clicked on view buttuon:

```
protected void ButtonView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-H7KQUT1;Initial Catalog=SAOS;Integrated Security=True";
    con.Open();

    string query1 = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE Date between '" + datepicker.Text + "'AND'" + datepicker1.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(query1, con);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();

    if (sdr.Read())
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        Label7.Text = "No records found!!";
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

The problem is here:

```
 string query1 = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE Date between '" + datepicker.Text + "'AND'" + datepicker1.Text + "'";
```

I have a column called `Student_ID` as the foreign key in table attendance.

Comment: show sample data and expected output and table names too

Comment: And its dangerous to use concate in a AdHoc query

Comment: so change your where clause to limit by student_ID?

Comment: can't show only a student attendance records--> For this you need to pass student_id to the query to fecth the data related him/her only

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 3):

```
string query1 = "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE Date between @startDate AND @endDate and Student_ID = @studentId";

SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = datepicker.Text;
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = datepicker1.Text;
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@studentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 100;
```